# Android Layout Not Laying Out Custom View as Expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am making an Android application using custom views. I have done this many times before but this time I seem to have encountered a weird issue.

When attempting to make the layout, either through XML or the layout editor, my custom view does not layout as expected. When I place one of my views to the right of an existing one, it appears to align to the left. I have attached an image to show what I mean
[image: Layout Issue]

I'm not certain what is causing this, it doesn't appear to happen with any other view, and has never happened before with previous applications despite me using similar code for the custom view.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before? If so, any suggestions?

I can put up the code for the view and other potentially relevant code if requested.

EDIT - Alright, coding as requested, hopefully it doesn't offend anyone too much.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.offthemap.sudokusolver.SudokuButton
    android:id="@+id/sudokuButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<com.offthemap.sudokusolver.SudokuButton
    android:id="@+id/sudokuButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sudokuButton2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom View:

```
package com.offthemap.sudokusolver;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class SudokuButton extends View 
{
private static Bitmap background, border, borderSelected;
private static Bitmap[] number;
private static int size = 100;
private int numberIndex = -1;

public SudokuButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context);
    Resources res = getResources();
    if (background == null){background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background), size, size, false);}
    if (border == null){border = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.border), size, size, false);}
    if (borderSelected == null){borderSelected = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.borderselected), size, size, false);}
    if (number == null)
    {
        number = new Bitmap[]{
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.one), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.two), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.three), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.four), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.five), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.six), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.seven), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.eight), size, size, false),
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.nine), size, size, false)
                };
        }
}

public void increaseNumber()
{
    numberIndex++;
    if (numberIndex == 9){numberIndex = -1;}
    invalidate();
}

public void setNumber(int newNumber)
{
    numberIndex = newNumber;
}

public static void setSize(int newSize)
{
    size = newSize;
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
    if (numberIndex != -1)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(number[numberIndex], 0, 0, null);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(border, 0, 0, null);
}

@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
 {
    setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec),    measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
 }

private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
{
    int preferred = background.getWidth();
    return getMeasurement(measureSpec, preferred);
    }

private int measureHeight(int measureSpec)
{
  int preferred = background.getHeight();
  return getMeasurement(measureSpec, preferred);
}

private int getMeasurement(int measureSpec, int preferred)
{
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
    int measurement = 0;

    switch(MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec))
  {
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        measurement = specSize;
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        measurement = Math.min(preferred, specSize);
        break;
    default:
        measurement = preferred;
        break;
  }
    return measurement;
}
}
```

SECOND EDIT - Appears it was just an issue with using static bitmaps, not sure why it was happening but removing it seemed to fix it.

Comment: xml content would be nice, also the code of your custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your xml where you define the layout_Right_of ?

Sometimes is a problem of if you define before the referenced view or after, i mean where you use de @+id or the @id if its already defined.

-- EDIT --

```
public class SudokuButton extends View 
{
```

To:

```
public class SudokuButton extends RelativeLayout
```

and:

```
<com.offthemap.sudokusolver.SudokuButton
android:id="@+id/sudokuButton1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sudokuButton2" />
```

To:

```
<com.offthemap.sudokusolver.SudokuButton
android:id="@+id/sudokuButton1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sudokuButton2" />
```

because is already defined in the preview component in the R.

Two comments, try extending from a ViewGroup like Relative or Linear Layout in your custom component, another thing is that you can reference from your second component to the first one without the @+id

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: The Eclipse interface by default seems to add the + to the @+id on it's own, and has worked fine in the past. Changing it seems to have made no difference.

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of extending RelativeLayout instead, is it not more logical to extend View as I am creating a custom View?

Comment: Let me explain it, its a good practice to use the tags in the correct way, the @+id its to add a new id to your R, eclipse will automatically add de + when he thinks its good but its not perfect, so you only put the + on the first definition of your id only, then reference it with @id.
For extending from a GroupView its because some methods like onMeasure, etc are correctly inherited from a GroupView, so its better to extend from that, try it and tell me if it works :)